# Laravel interaction with external program

Tags: laravel, process, jobs, interactive

I would need to interact with an external program as follow:

- On submit form the controller launches the external program
- The program will send a code by SMS and wait for it for verification
- The controller returns a new view with a form to ask for this code
- On submit form the controller provides the code to the program

The main issue is this program is running in a blocking mode (it will wait for the code and return only after the verification), therefore I cannot execute it directly from the controller with symfony/process.

Instead I execute it in a queue job (is it the right thing to do?) which is launched on the first form submit, but I can't find out how to send to this running job the code obtained by the second form submit.

Is there a way to send information from a controller to an already running job?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your workflow a little bit.

1. On submit form, the controller dispatches a job, that launches the external program
2. The program will send a code by SMS and wait for it for verification
3. When job with step 2 finishes (verification is done), it will fire off Notification, that will contain link to a new view with the form.
4. On submit form the controller provides the code to the program

Simple point is to not block the request, let the job handle it, as you pointed out in original question.
Form can be built anyway, implement echo server that will help you deliver message via websocket.

> Is there a way to send information from a controller to an already running job?

No.